# Managing Sharepoint Service permissions with distributed architecture

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, access

I have following architecture for SharePoint and I wanted to know best permission set up. Currently we have fresh install of SharePoint Foundation server with the services running as shown in the image below.

[image: SharePoint Architecture]

We are moving the database engine to a dedicated SQL server because its running standard edition. However the  dedicated SQL server doesn't have enough hard disk space. So we plan to use existing network drive which is coming from a file server.

Consider we have created  folder on the network drive called "Sharepoint Database" where all the .mdf,.ndf and .ldf files will be copied. The SQL database of SharePoint will now be hosted by the SQL server shown in the middle with files on the network drive.

Under what account now I need to run the services on the SharePoint box? Which of the accounts need to be a domain account ?
My main concern is which service will actually try to read/write to database on the network drive?

Comment: I take it that this is for SQL Server 2012?  The only permissions that need to be applied to the file share are for the database engine that runs the SQL Server service (which must be a domain user).

Prior to SQL 2012, SMB file shares are not a supported location for SQL databases.

Comment: The SQL Server (in the middle) is running 2008 edition. My questions remains unanswered. If the database engine service should run as a domain account which also has read/write permissions for the shared drive, what account should the services of SharePoint run on ?

Comment: You cannot use SQL 2008 and store your MDF/LDF/NDFs on an SMB share.  If you were running SQL 2012, your Database Engine account would be the only account that would need access to the share and MDF/NDF/LDF files.  SharePoint should have its own service accounts.  As a starting point, use Todd's list: http://toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=237

Comment: Thanks. I think I am in trouble then. We need to add additional hard drives on the middle SQL Server or upgrade the sqlexpress on Sharepoint server to Sharepoint Express 2012 and then may be try using BLOB storage. Just for the records, here is the link about using SMB for SQL Server 2012 [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh759341.aspx)

Comment: By the way , can I not map the network drive as say Z: The credentials used to map the network drive would be the one that the database engine runs on. Could this be a workaround ?

Comment: No, it must be a local device to the SQL Server.  SQL Server knows the difference between a Local Device and a Mapped Drive.  Plus, mapped drives are horrendously unreliable.